# Diaconate vs. Deacon

Tags: etymology, nouns, greek, derivation

A plurality of deacons is called a diaconate. What is the reason for this vowel change ("e" to "i") for these words? Are there any other words that illustrate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *deacon* is an anglicization of the borrowed Latin word *diacon* (which itself was originally Greek), so the vowel change is the other way around.  Over time, *diacon* became *deacon*.

The reason for the difference in the vowels between *deacon* and *diaconate* is likely because of when these two words were borrowed.

*Deacon* has been around in English for some time; the earliest uses in the OED date back to 1000 AD (early Middle English).

*Diaconate* was not borrowed at that time, nor was *diaconate* in any way derived from *deacon* when it entered English.  Instead, it was borrowed directly from Latin; in particular, there is one OED reference in the 1700s and everything else is from the mid-1800s.

So, *deacon* has been around since the Middle English period and has been through a thousand years of vowel change, while *diaconate* entered the language fairly recently.

Another example of this: *pope* (from Old English) and *papal* / *papacy* (1400s): all came from Latin *papa*.

Comment: As it is true that pope comes from Latin papa, diaconos was Greek and found its way into Latin as diaconus.